# Average of a Series in a DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, series

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
values
[0.0,12.34,223.12,4.55,...]
[0.0,78.12,12.90,...]
.
.
.
```

I am trying to calculate the average of the value column and store that number in a new column.

The dataframe only holds a single column at the moment and the length of each array in the values column is not strict.

Expected output:

```
value                             average
[0.0,12.34,223.12,4.55,...]        77.87
[0.0,78.12,12.90,...]              12.11            
.
.
.
```

Np.mean() will not work when I try to loop through the dataframe using iterrows().

Essentially I need to expand the code below to calculate all the averages in a dataframe:

```
np.mean(df_average_pace.paces[0])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a series of lists. This means vectorisation isn't possible. You can use a Python-level loop via [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) (or, equivalently, [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)) and [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
from statistics import mean
df['average'] = df['value'].map(mean)
```

Here's a demo:

```
from statistics import mean
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [[1, 4, 1, 2], [2, 4, 6], [9, 2, 5]]})
df['average'] = df['value'].map(mean)

print(df)

          value   average
0  [1, 4, 1, 2]  2.000000
1     [2, 4, 6]  4.000000
2     [9, 2, 5]  5.333333
```

Comment: `map` is smart  :-)

Comment: @W-B, Yup, your solution is, of course, better if all lists same size :)

Comment: Just adding that all lists are not the same size

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
pd.DataFrame(df.value.tolist()).mean(1)
Out[541]: 
0    2.000000
1    4.000000
2    5.333333
dtype: float64
```